# Document object instead of JSON when calling webservice from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I am running an Ajax call from javascript to a webservice:

```
 $.ajax(signingURI + "?fileName=" + fileName)
        .done(function (data){
  });
```

My webservice:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public string PolicyGenerator(string fileName){
       return "{\"res\":\"asdasda\"}" ;
 }
```

When inspecting the data argument I get a **XML document object instead of JSON**. What I am doing wrong?

In the watch expression:

```
data: document
URL: ""
anchors: HTMLCollection[0]
applets: HTMLCollection[0]
baseURI: null
body: null
characterSet: null
charset: undefined
childNodes: NodeList[1]
compatMode: "CSS1Compat"
constructor: DocumentConstructor
cookie: [Exception: DOMException]
defaultCharset: undefined
defaultView: null
......
```

Comment: What document type is your server returning?  Since you've not specified any document type in your ajax call, the jQuery code is going to go with what the server indicates is the document type.  If your server is indicating an HTML document, then jQuery may be trying to treat it as that.  You can also look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see EXACTLY what is coming across the wire from your server.

Comment: Hi, it returned text/xml; charset=utf-8

Comment: So, that's how jQuery treated it as an XML document.

Comment: How can I return JSON?

Comment: The best way would be to fix your server so that it is returning a JSON type, not an XML type.  I'm not familiar with your server environment to know how to do that.  You could also force jQuery to try to interpret it as JSON by passing `dataType: 'json'` as an option on the ajax call.

Comment: What server technologies/libraries are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use HTTP GET, decorate your webservice method with [`ScriptMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public string PolicyGenerator(string fileName){
      return "{\"res\":\"asdasda\"}" ;
}
```

Also, **don't manually construct JSON** on either end of your transaction.  jQuery serializes objects for you.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: { fileName: 'test.jpg' }
});
```

With GET requests, the `data` will be serialized onto a query string.  With POST, it is sent in the request entity body in standard x-www-form-urlencoded style.  If you want to send  JSON in the POST body, use `JSON.stringify`.

Your server-side function should return a serializable class.  .NET will output proper JSON for you.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public PolicyGeneratorResponse PolicyGenerator(string fileName){
      return new PolicyGeneratorResponse(...);
}

...

class PolicyGeneratorResponse {
    public string res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dataType to the request:

```
$.ajax(signingURI + "?fileName=" + fileName, { dataType: 'json' })
        .done(function (data){
});
```

Comment: My guess is that this will work, though it would be better to fix the server to set the data as JSON in the first place.

Comment: Hi, nope, enters the fail function with error which is the returned string ("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://temp.org/">{"res":"asdasda"}</string>")

Comment: Oh, well, in that case the problem is that your web service is returning an XML document. :P Can you update the web service? [WebMethod] is specifically intended to return XML.

Comment: How can I update it to return JSON?. It's weird because I work with other function and didn't have this problem having XML

Comment: Is your other function using the [WebMethod] attribute or something different?

Comment: could we see one of those methods? I'm surprised that they can return JSON without some difference.

Comment: Found the answer, writing it down

Answer (score 0):

Something is very weird going on. Seems that the webservice does return JSON, but when I used the `.done` callback I couldn't read it.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: signingURI,
         data: "{'fileName':'" + encodeURI('test.jpg') + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(msg){
```

Using the success callback inside the other properties gave me JSON. So weird, or is it?.